# Add index to dbt model column?

Tags: postgresql, dbt

We are considering using dbt to manage models in our PostgreSQL data warehouse. Since dbt models are SQL select statements, there doesn't seem to be an obvious, or documented, way to specify that a particular column should have an index.

How can we specify column indexes on dbt models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/postgres-configs#indexes):

```sql
{{ config(
    materialized = 'table',
    indexes=[
      {'columns': ['column_a'], 'type': 'hash'},
      {'columns': ['column_a', 'column_b'], 'unique': True},
    ]
)}}

select ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this exact issue myself and made the following package for this use case:

[dbt-postgres-utils](https://hub.getdbt.com/sgoley/postgres_utils/latest/)

1. Installation

Include the following in your packages.yml file:

```
packages:
  - package: sgoley/postgres_utils
    version: 0.2.0
```

then you can run `dbt deps` and the dbt package manager will setup the related macros in your project locally under `project_dir/dbt_modules/postgres_utils`.

2. Usage

After that, *table* models can have an index or unique index built with a posthook like:

```
{{
config({
    "post-hook": [
      "{{ postgres_utils.index(this, 'id')}}",
    ],
    })
}}
```

Of course if you add this to a view model, your `dbt run` will throw an error.

Feel free to make additional requests, submissions, or more here on the project repo:

[github: sgoley/dbt-postgres-utils](https://github.com/sgoley/dbt-postgres-utils)

Additional features I'm working on are:

- convert syntax of `index` and `uindex` functions to "create or replace"
- specify index types (btree, hash, etc.)

Comment: For what it's worth, they are discussing adding indexing to dbt-postgres directly: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/804

Comment: Here is the pull request that intends to add indexing to dbt-postgres: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/pull/3106

Comment: It might be good to contribute index-related changes from dbt-postgres-utils directly to dbt-postgres :-)

Comment: Yes, I'm following that issue closely but have much more in the works than just index macros: https://trello.com/b/jG0KfNzl/dbt-postgres-utils

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/postgres-profile) indexing a manual job:

> Make sure to create indexes for columns that are commonly used in
> joins or where clauses.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I hope index definitions will be included in future releases, as we would like to include index definitions under revision control.

Comment: Ah, found the related feature request: https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/804

Comment: I first searched StackOverflow and the DBT Discourse for any suggestions.